# Complementary DNA(C++)

Tags: string, dna-sequence

Task:Write a code to the new string of Dna According to its pattern. Just so you know In DNA strings, symbols "A" and "T" are complements of each other, as "C" and "G".
Fore example:`DNA_strand ("ATTGC") //returns "TAACG"` or `DNA_strand ("GTAT") //returns "CATA"`
My Code=>

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
std::string DNAStrand(const std::string& dna)
{
  std::string Sym;
  std::string c;
  std::stringstream s;
  s << Sym;
  s >> c;
  for(int i = 0; i < dna.size() - 1; i++) {
      switch (dna[i]) {
          case ('A'):
          Sym[i] = 'T';
          break;
          case ('T'): 
          Sym[i] = 'A';
          break;
          case ('C'):
          Sym[i] = 'G';
          break;
          case ('G'):
          Sym[i] = 'C';
          break;
          default:
          std::cout << "invalid";
} return c.str();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << DNAStrand("ATTGC") << "\n"; //retun "TAACG"
  std::cout << DNAStrand("GTAT") << "\n";  //retun "CATA"
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What does this code do when run? Why is that wrong? Show example input, desired output, and current output; explain problems in full; quote error messages in full.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `vector<string>`, but in the `if` statements, you are setting the elements of the `vector` to `char`s. You want to build a `string`, not a `vector<string>`.

You should replace subsequent `if` statements with `else if`, or use a `switch` statement. Otherwise `if` statements subsequent to a satisfied `if` statement are executed needlessly.

Replace this `vector` with an [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/). Naming the stream as `s`, you would append a `char` named `c` with `s << c`. At the end of iterating over `dna`, return `s.str()`.

Comment: how should I replace the vector with an ostringstream??I`m confused a little

Comment: @PooryaKeshavarzi You are setting characters as the elements of a vector of strings. Get rid of the vector, and push the characters to an ostringstream instead. Then get the result by calling .str() on the ostringstream.

Comment: I updated my question.Tell me what to change

Comment: Read the documentation for string and ostringstream, if you want to use that. If you want to pre-allocate the string, then you need to initialise it with the right size.